# Is this a good solution design?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I have three main tables, WorkOrders, Computers and Tasks. WorkOrders is an order to repair a computer. So has the computer that will be repair, date and so on.

Computers are the computers that must be repair if one is failed. Finally I have the tasks that I can do in a computer.

In a first approximation the relation between work order and computer is 1:N because a computer can be repaired many times, but a work order is only for one computer.

The relation between computer and task is 1:N because one computer may need many tasks to be repaired but one task is done in a computer.

So the relation could be set at this way:

```
WorkOrders(IDOrder, IDComputer, ...)
Computers(IDComputer, ...)
Tasks(IDTask, IDComputer,...)
```

However this don't let me to know what task are made in an work order. Because if a computer is repaired many times, how I know which of the task is of one work order of from another?

So I am thinking in the possibility to use a relation table in this way:

```
CommonTable(IDOrder, IDComputer, IDTask,...)
```

But in this way it seems that the task can be in many computers and many orders, and this is not correct in theory.

Other solution is to add in task the IDOrder, but in this case a I have a cycle in the relationships, and I think that this is not correct.

So I would like to know if this is a good solution in practice or there are a better one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task should be related to WorkOrder, not computer.  You then can use Task (to) WorkOrder (to) Computer to find the COmputer for the TAsk.